# Autocomplete form in jHipster project

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, jhipster

I am trying to implement autocomplete in the form in jHipster project using PrimeNg and guided by this manual 
https://antoniogoncalves.org/2018/11/08/jhipster-angular-primeng-and-autocomplete/. Example from git works well.

***purchaseAgreementDetailsUpdateComponent.ts***

```
export class PurchaseAgreementDetailsUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
   purchaseAgreementDetails: IPurchaseAgreementDetails;
   nomenclaturas: INomenclatura[];
   selectedNom : INomenclatura;
   suggestedNoms : INomenclatura[];

   constructor(
    protected nomenclaturaService: NomenclaturaService,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.nomenclaturaService.query().subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<INomenclatura[]>) => {
            this.nomenclaturas = res.body;
        },
        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );
}
searchLanguages($event) {
    this.languageService.query({'name.contains': $event.query}).subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<ILanguage[]>) => {
            this.suggestedLanguages = res.body;
        },
        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );
}

captureSelectedLanguage($event) {
    this.selectedLanguage = $event;
    this.contact.languageId = $event.id;
    this.contact.languageName = $event.name;
}
```

***purchaseAgreementDetailsUpdateComponent.html***

```
  <p-autoComplete id="field_language" 
  name="language"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" field="name"
  [suggestions]="suggestedLanguages"                                            
  (completeMethod)="searchLanguages($event)"                                     
  (onSelect)="captureSelectedLanguage($event)"
  required>
 </p-autoComplete>
```

But when i typing there are no any suggestions although i see http-reqs and responses with filtered entities according typed values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved by adding:

```
   import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
```

to app.module.ts